# SharePoint list with column that can add additional fields

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to create a list where one of the columns has 6 options to choose from and if option 3 is selected it adds additional fields to that record and if option 6 is select it add completely different fields.

Is there anyway to do to this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to customize the List forms using Infopath. See [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/laurhar/infopath-2010-customize-a-sharepoint-list-form) for more details. You can hide/show the columns in the add/edit forms based on the selection.